# 27 inch monitor with 2560x1440 resolution will it work with laptop geforce 540m 1gb?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I got a simple question - Im going to buy an external monitor for my laptop which will be an ASUS PB278QR with 2560x1440 resolution - will my laptop handle it (geforce 540m 1GB) ? I will use it only for work (Google Chrome and some IDE). Will it work on HDMI port or only on VGA port ?

My laptop is Asus x53s with Intel Core i7 2670QM, 12GB Ram nad geforce 540m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having looked into this a bit more, it seems that your graphics card *should* be able to run that display at full resolution over HDMI.

According to the HDMI version comparison at [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_comparison) HDMI 1.3 would allow 2560x1600 and [your graphics card](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-540m/features) supports HDMI 1.4, so it should actually work.

```
HDMI version:  1.0          1.1          1.2          1.3           1.4          2.0
Resolution:    1920×1200p   1920×1200p   1920×1200p   2560×1600p   4096×2160    4096×2160p
Refresh rate:  60 Hz        60 Hz        60 Hz        60 Hz        24 Hz        60 Hz
```

My mistake in my original answer (below) was thinking that HDMI 2.0 added support above HD, when in fact the difference is that 4k was already supported but at a lower frame rate of 24 Hz rather than 60hz.  DVI on the other hand has not seen as much active development as HDMI and only supports 1900x1200 on single link and 2560x1600 on dual-link as below.

VGA is another kettle of fish entirely and depends on another piece of hardware to convert the digital signal used by the graphics card into an analogue signal: the [RAMDAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAMDAC).  For each pixel visible on the screen the RAMDAC takes the digital value and then outputs it as an analogue value on 3 signal lines.  To get above 2048x1536 you need a very fast RAMDAC to ensure that it can slew the output signal fast enough to avoid bleeding one signal into the next and having a disappointing picture.

Analogue signals are much less resistant to noise than digital signals and so cable quality matters a whole lot more.  A [current generation card](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-980-ti/specifications) lists its maximum VGA resolution as 2048x1536 and while you *might* be able to get your graphics card to output 2560 x 1600 at something like 30Hz, or maybe higher rates, there are real signal integrity problems you can and probably will run into.

From Wikipedia [VGA:Cable Quality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA_connector#Cable_quality):

> The same VGA cable can be used with a variety of supported VGA resolutions, ranging from 640×350px @70 Hz (24 MHz of signal bandwidth) to 1280×1024px (SXGA) @85 Hz (160 MHz) and up to 2048×1536px (QXGA) @85 Hz (388 MHz). There are no standards defining the quality required for each resolution, but higher-quality cables typically contain coaxial wiring and insulation which make them thicker. A quality cable should not suffer from signal crosstalk which occurs when the signals in one wire induce unwanted currents in adjacent wires, ghosting which occurs when impedance mismatches cause signals to be reflected (note that ghosting with long cables may not be the fault of the cable but may instead be caused by equipment with incorrect termination or by use of passive splitters), and other signal degradation effects; shorter VGA cables are less likely to introduce significant degradation.

Due to the noise problems and rise of digital signalling there has been little to no need to use particularly fast RAMDACs on newer graphics cards so VGA essentially stagnated and has died as far as monitor connections are concerned.

---

The following is kept for posterity.

If you only have a HDMI output then probably not. Above 1920 x 1080 you need HDMI 2.0 which only got support recently  by the 900 series graphics processors. Below those you will have 1.4 or lower which does not support the higher resolution.

If you have a DVI connector then this will probably work using a dual-link DVI cable. From the Geforce 540m [features page](http://www.geforce.co.uk/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-540m/features):

> #### Dual-link DVI Support
>
> Able to drive industry’s largest and highest resolution flat-panel displays up to 2560x1600 and with support for High-bandwidth Digital Content Protection (HDCP).

You will need to make certain you have a full dual link cable, i.e. the connector is not missing a batch of pins in the centre.

[image]

Comment: It may be wise to include that the monitor is likely to provide the dual link cable. I got myself a DELL 27" with identical resolution, and it had this cable too.

Comment: I dont have DVI port in my laptop i only got HDMI and VGA port. Can I use VGA port insted ? I know that picture will be analog but can it be displaied in 2560x1440 resolution via VGA port ?

Comment: @born2fr4g I have investigated further and corrected my post. I believe your HDMI output *should* be capable of driving that display, so long as the display is HDMI 1.3 or above.

Comment: @Mokubai - thank you for your answer - what about VGA port ? Can I display that high resolution over it ?

Comment: @born2fr4g being an analog signal VGA is harder to nail down and is even more dependant on the electronics. The  maximum resolution listed for a GTX770 is 2048x1536 for VGA so I doubt yours would manage any higher than that. Being an analog signal there are more problems with signal integrity and quality. VGA would look awful at that resolution and I couldn't recommend it to anyone with even vaguely good eyesight.

Comment: I will be aware of that. Thank you for a great answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Separate monitor is separate monitor, extended displays are quite common and most APU / GPU manufacturers allow different resolutions on different screens. I have a GTX 660 in my tower and simply opening up the NVIDIA Control Panel (right click, should be there if you've installed drivers) reveals an option "Change Resolution" under "Display", that allows you to set the resolution of each display. Whether it's HDMI, DVI, VGA etc,is not too big of a concern, there are adapters available. Just see what ports your laptop has available and see if they match up with those of the ports on your monitor, if they match up, great, if not, buy adapters.

Comment: You're quite mistaken with the "Whether its HDMI, DVI, VGA..."... part. For a resolution this high, you need a lot of bandwidth. This rules out VGA by definition. DVI will work, but only with a dual link DVI cable. The monitor should provide one though. HDMI will work with version 2.0 and up.

Comment: hmm I didn't know that, I'm not too familiar with extended displays but I've never had any issues setting them up. Bandwidth and cable type actually never cross my mind when doing so, thanks for the heads up, I'll know to pay more attention now.