# Sceptre C35 UltraWide Curved Display HDMI Problems

Tags: display, hdmi

I just bought this Ultrawide and for the most part works great. I just bought a 2 port HDMI switch to switch between my work and gaming laptop. The problem I've been having is the HDMI pushing from my laptop isn't working with this display. I have one port at 100hz and two at 60hz. I've connected the HDMI from my gaming laptop into another display I have with an HDMI and it works fine. That display is 24". I have connected my Xbox to the Sceptre display and it works over HDMI so the HDMI ports on the display seem to be working and not defective.

At this point I am leaning on a problem with my laptop to this particular display and trying to figure that out. I have also tried to use HDMI from my business laptop and it's the same problem. However, when I use the display port for this screen on my business laptop it works great. Does anybody know what could be causing this and what else I could do to troubleshoot this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Not all laptops support outputting at QHD or 4K resolutions. Many of them can only put out 4K over displayport, but their HDMI ports are limited to 4K@30 or less. https://superuser.com/questions/1475282/intel-hd-graphics-620-does-my-display-adapter-support-hdmi-2-0-necessary-for-a/1475289#1475289

Comment: @Mokubai, thank you for the info! My gaming laptop is a Lenovo Y70 Touch. It's a little older but sounds like it may have some compatibility issues here.Is there anything I can do to get this screen to display from my laptop?

Comment: Sadly no. The output is what it is and the best you are likely to get out of it is 1920x1080@60Hz or 4K at 30Hz. Many older machines, especially those with Intel integrated graphics as a "power saving" GPU will be limited to HDMI 1.4. If you had a Displayport output then you might be able to get better, but apparently you only have that on your business machine. https://superuser.com/questions/1037013/27-inch-monitor-with-2560x1440-resolution-will-it-work-with-laptop-geforce-540m/1037020#1037020